# The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'

Tags: exception, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, dynamic-data

I am working on a Dynamic data.

after creating a dynamic model and registering in global.asax, like

```
DefaultModel.RegisterContext(typeof(masterEntities1),new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

when i run an application, it shows a list of tables but when i click any of the table it throws an exception:

***The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.***

but i haven't declare any query into my application.

Comment: i have came across some website which contains the following information.

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework as the data model then you would have to update your query method for every entity. You need to add the ordering clause. The reason that you need to do this is because by default the query method is not ordered and in Dynamic Data project templates, paging is enabled for the List and List details templates. In the case if you do not order the result of your query method and use paging you will get the following exception when you access the entity in List/List details template

Comment: such as: public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()

        {

            return this.ObjectContext.Products.OrderBy(p=>p.ProductID);

        }

Comment: but now the problem is where should i orderby the entities in Entities data model so that when it map to the the relational table it orderby the list before it call a method skip?

Answer (score 13):

You must call `.OrderBy'` on your query if you use the `.Skip` method. For example if you were using something similar to the following:

`results = results.Skip(pageNumber * size).Take(size);`

In the case above you would have previously had to use the `.OrderBy` to order the query if you are planning on using paging methods or something of the like. If you have an `Id` field, adding this onto your original query expression should eliminate the error:

`.OrderBy(x => x.Id);`

Comment: Since ordering by ID (if the data comes from a database) is implied, can't that assumption be made by the skip method as well?