# Entity Framework Code First ToList method timing out on SQL Azure

Tags: linq, entity-framework, t-sql, c#-4.0, azure-sql-database

We have a view which is invoked using EF code first. It uses a Linq syntax and is straight forward. After working for some time the query times out at ToList method. Even at that time the query works instantly from SSMS.

One thing noticed was dropping and recreating the view solves the issue, but after an indefinite time the issue resurfaces.

The DB is on SQL Azure and checked for any locks on the object and nothing was found.

Has anyone faced such an issue or similar. Could you please help???

**The actual query which gets blocked**

```
var results = facilityId == Guid.Empty ?
                            (from c in Context.CallLists
                             where c.AgencyId == agencyId
                             select c)
                               :
                            (from c in Context.CallLists
                             where c.AgencyId == agencyId && c.InitiatedFacilityId == facilityId
                             select c);

if (request.Page > 0)
            {
                results = results.Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize);
            }

        return results.Take(request.PageSize);
```

Comment: Does the query time out every time or is it intermittent? How much data is it retrieving from the database?

Comment: This "locking" is intermittent .. The DB has just 30 thousand + rows, and at a time only 25 is shown up on the UI.. But once the "lock" occurs all of EF query to this gets timed out ..

Comment: Can you include the LINQ query in your question?

Comment: I've updated the actual post for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Change it into an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` by calling `.OrderBy()` before `Skip` and `Take`. I think it's currently retrieving all rows from the table. Normally I'd have expected [an exception to be thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222694/the-method-skip-is-only-supported-for-sorted-input-in-linq-to-entities-the-me) but I'm not sure why it's not been - are you using the results? Have you tried running it with a Page > 0?

Try this:

```
var results;

if (facilityId != Guid.Empty)
{
    results = Context.CallLists.Where(c => c.AgencyId == agencyId).OrderBy(c => c.Something);
}
else
{
    results = Context.CallLists.Where(c => c.AgencyId == agencyId && c.InitiatedFacilityId == facilityId).OrderBy(c => c.Something);
}

if (request.Page > 0)
{
    results = results.Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize);
}

return results.Take(request.PageSize);
```

In addition to this, you need to come up with a way of handling the SQL Azure transient errors. This is basically a subset of errors that can be thrown when executing queries in SQL Azure, which should be handled by waiting and retrying the operation, usually with increasing wait times between retries until you finally accept a failure. Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/12/11/sql-azure-and-entity-framework-connection-fault-handling.aspx).

Comment: Greg, There is an orderby which I missed to copy because this was done conditionally in multiple line of code. So that does not seem to be issue. But thanks for suggesting the transient fault handling. That definitely needs to be done! But the current problem does not seem to be because of this.

Comment: What's the query that's being performed on the database? Can you call `.ToString()` on the query and see what it's actually running? All I can think of is that it's querying all the rows for some reason.